# Scroll snap not working on chrome, but works on firefox

Tags: css, sass

I've been trying to use CSS scroll snapping for a website. It works perfectly on Firefox but not on chrome. I'm trying to find out what the problem could be. I'm using SCSS. [Here is a snippet of the code.](https://codepen.io/realmortgen/pen/poexOae)

```
body {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;


.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  
    section {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 99vw;
        height: 99vh;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
```

Comment: The MDN demo also seem to behave the same: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts, maybe a browser bug

Answer (score 0):

scroll-snap-type is not supported by older chrome versions.
Is your version maybe outdated?

[image]

https://caniuse.com/?search=croll-snap-type

Comment: I've checked the version of my chrome and it is indeed up-to-date with the current version 91.0.4472.101. To clarify the question a bit more as well. Snap scroll does work in chrome, but it scrolls first and then it snaps, while Firefox directly snaps to the next or previous section.